# Delphi - Include TD32 Debug Info

Tags: delphi

I am using Delphi 5.0 and trying to make applcation compatible with Test Complete. For that I have to build my application by selecting the Project --> Project Options --> Linker -->Include TD32 Debug Info. This all works good, but question is there any disadvantage of including that debug info in application. One thing I have noticed is the applcation size is increased 3 times around. Please let me know how much safe it is to use application with selecting Include TD32 Debug Info.

Thanks for help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you include TD32 debug info in a shipping version of your application, then you also include the full source for your program. You probably only want to use TD32 debug info for in-house builds, and ship a version without TD32.

SmartBear have a utility called [StripTDS](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/33105/). This allows you have have the TD32 info external to the executable. It achieves this by removing it from the executable and saving it to a separate file. This may very well be what you are looking for.

Comment: exact answer i am looking for.. :)